# How to use the old value and the new value of a Variable in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, assign, control-flow

I want to use the old value and the new value of a Variable. But I am
confused about when the `Assign Op` is applied.

Here is a simple example. The outputs of `output` and `output2` are different.

```
v = tf.Variable(0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(v.initializer)

    new_v = v.assign(v + 10)
    output = v + 0 # `v` is evaluated before the assignment ?
    output2 = v  # `v` is evaluated after the assignment ?

    print(sess.run([ output, output2, new_v])) 
    print(sess.run(output))
```

The result is

> [0, 10, 10]
>
> 10

Please advise me what is the proper way to use the old value and the new value of a Variable. Thanks.

---

According to  chrisz's answer, I tried `tf.control_dependencies` to get the old value of `v`. But the result is not what I expected. I still need to add `0` to `v` to get the old value.

Here is the test code. And I add a `0` to get the same result as above. Otherwise, the result of `output_old` will be `10`

```
v = tf.Variable(0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(v.initializer)
    output_old = v + 0         # If I want the old value, this extra add is needed
    with tf.control_dependencies([output_old]):
        new_v = v.assign(v + 10)
        output_new = new_v

    print(sess.run([output_old, output_new, new_v])) 
    print(sess.run(output_old))
```

Comment: You need to add a control dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, when the fetches are independent, there's in general **no guarantee** in which order they are calculated (a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48465510/712995) with a similar case).

E.g., if you run your script in a loop, you may occasionally get `[10, 10, 10]`, which would mean that `new_v` is evaluated first. On my machine, I couldn't make `output2` evaluate to `0`, so it's most probably implementation feature, but I won't be surprised if it changes from platform to platform or from version to version. The only guaranteed value is `new_v` which will always be `10`; both `output` and `output2` can be either `0` or `10`.

To answer your question, the best way to get both values simultaneously is to add another variable and use `tf.control_dependencies` context:

```
v = tf.Variable(0)
tmp = tf.Variable(0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([v.initializer, tmp.initializer])
    saved_v = tmp.assign(v)
    with tf.control_dependencies([saved_v]):
      new_v = v.assign(v + 10)
      old_v = tf.identity(saved_v)
      # At this point, `new_v` is guaranteed to be 10, 
      # `old_v` and `saved_v` are guaranteed to be 0
```

Note that it won't in general work without `tf.control_dependencies`, as `old_v` and `saved_v` can be evaluated after `new_v`. Your trick with a dependency on `output_old = v + 0` also works, but it looks more like a hack to me. In any case, you can't get avoid `tf.control_dependencies`.